# how to maintain state/queue for web API response result

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have 100+ applications (from 100 + box) which call my web api (hosted in separate box) and push some JSON result.

Currently I'm writing a file for each response and then another service looks all the file and aggregate the files which will produce a new file each max 300KB in size.

How to simplify this process, can I use some in-memory queue, how to maintain state, etc. please suggest?

Comment: This question is very open to opinions, there are so many ways of doing this: in-memory, some kind of queue eg ServiceBus, MSMQ, SQS, RabbitMQ, or writting to a table in a DB then aggregating etc.

Comment: Hi, have you considered using a cloud provider (AWS, Azure, etc) ? Usually every cloud provider has solutions for the problems you're facing. If you opt for AWS I can help you with more details.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Petrut, I'm looking some on-prem solution only, may be I will push the web api result into C# `blockingCollection`, then will subscribe to it and create files